# How to assign IIS_IUSRS

Tags: iis-7.5

I can't figure this IIS_IUSRS group.  As far as the asp.net worker process in IIS 7.5 don't you have to give that group write permission to whatever (web.config, etc.)?

Or is IIS_IUSRS the group that runs an app pool by default and I simply need to add some user to that group?

I'm trying to get rid of a permission issue over UNC path where IIS can't read the web.config and tried to add IIS_IUSRS to the security tab of the web.config file but it has no idea what IIS_IUSRS is...when I try to search for users to add to the security list on that file in windows explorer in Win 7.

Answer (score 4):

I figured a solution for this, just go to app pool and right click for edit permissions, in sharing options just type IIS_IUSRS and select your machine name and it automatically creates a group.

Answer (score 3):

`IIS_IUSRS` is analogous to the old IIS6 `IIS_WPG` group. It's a built-in group with it's security configured such that any member of this group can act as an application pool identity.

For more information see:

> [Understanding Built-In User and Group Accounts in IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the pool accounts' group and yes, you are supposed to ACL IIS_IUSRS. But not write access, for your application code and web.config, you only need to assign it read access.